# Conversion with template variables c++

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion

In addition to following template struct

```
template <int N>
struct mytype {
    using type = typename std::conditional<N <= 8, std::uint8_t,
                 typename std::conditional<N <= 16, std::uint16_t,
                 typename std::conditional<N <= 32, std::uint32_t,
                 typename std::conditional<N <= 64, std::uint64_t,
                 typename std::uintmax_t>::type>::type>::type>::type;
};
```

I have a member variable `mytype<N> m_aNumber` and want to give within a method a value. The value in this case however needs to be a float.
So naturally I added a line like

```
m_aNumber = (mytype<N>) (..my float value..);
```

This leads to following error:

```
Error: no matching function for call to 'mytype<32>::mytype(float)'
     m_aNumber = (mytype<N>) (..my float value.. );
               ^
```

What would be the best way to convert it from a float to my custom type, that will ever be an int, just with different sizes?

Comment: is your attempt to assign a float to `mytype<N>` instead of to `typename mytype<N>::type` intentional ?

Comment: If it is, you'll need a suitable assignment operator or constuctor, of course.

Comment: If you ask like that, I guess not. The only thing I intend to do is to simply cast the float into the same type that m_aNumber has. Like this int m_aNumber = (int) (floatstuff), but since m_aNumber is mytype<N>, I thought I need to cast (mytype<N>)

Comment: Well, sounds like your `m_aNumber` should be of type `typename mytype<N>::type`. `mytype<N>` is just an empty struct.

Comment: One problem is that `mytype<N>` is a specific type, which is different from `mytype<N>::type`. Attemptying to cast to `mytype<N>` is the same as asking the compiler to create an `mytype<N>` object instance.

Comment: @T.C. That would lead to this error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'mytype<32>' and 'mytype<32>::type {aka unsigned int}')
         m_aNumber = typename mytype<N>::type (... );
                     ^

Comment: @TreeOfLife http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/300f187df5d35f3b

Comment: @Anton Savin with 'typename' before the assignment, it works. Can you transform it into an answer? Thank you guys for helping again.